# Why doesn't interface work when defining a type that uses enum as property key?

Tags: typescript

If I have an enum and want to use the enum values as key in some objects, I can declare the types like so:

```
enum Foo {
    X, Y
}

let map: FooMapType = {
    [Foo.X]: "abc",
    [Foo.Y]: "def"
}

type FooMapType = {
    [key in Foo]: string
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However, if I try to do the same thing using interface:

```
interface FooMapInterface {
    [key in Foo]: string
}
```

I get these errors:

```
TS1169: A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
TS2464: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
TS2304: Cannot find name 'key'.
```

Why is there a difference between interface vs type in this case? What is the restriction on interface, if any, that resulted in this design decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to use [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) keys (of the form `[P in K]: T` where `K` is a key-like type) as keys of an `interface`. Right now you get some confusing error messages because the compiler misinterprets what you are doing as using a [computed property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-5.html#computed-properties) declaration (of the form `[k]: U` where `k` is a key-like *value*, not a type).  There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#18299](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18299) asking for some fix for these error messages.

I don't know if there's any canonical documentation that says exactly why you cannot use mapped types here.  In addition to normal properties whose keys are statically-known string or numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), interfaces are allowed to have [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures), [construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures), [method signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#class-heritage), and [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), all of which are also allowed inside `class` instance types.  Mapped types are not in the list of accepted things.

---

If you want to make an `interface` out of your mapped type, you can do it by [extending](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) the mapped type as a new interface.  You are allowed to extend a named type with statically known keys.  And since the keys of `FooMapType` are statically known (as opposed to some unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type), you can write this:

```
interface FooMapInterface extends FooMapType { } // okay
```

And see that it works:

```
declare const fooMapInterface: FooMapInterface;
fooMapInterface[Foo.X].toUpperCase(); // okay
```

So you can get this behavior, you just can't write it *directly*.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvAsAKClAGgGigTXQF910AbYAFyggEMAHALlgQFkGAVAT3uCgF5k6TAG14cAHRYAuswBEtAEYBjOTmFQxCCfllQ5AE2AAzOcVJpKPPuPb1uvAUIyaA1sC5QAliBZw9AM6UAE4+AObmaBY+lMDBxrTKNmwMAJIgsfGJfMAAHrEgBgF+dg58SFAkUWhGymS0wXzKcCBBUMYp9OmZCUnMtmkZcb3AANzoHXB23cPZWpIyEpRwAKr0vMEAwrQBwAAUAJSjUAD0J1BwrrRcFkA)